# How inheritance works in case of anonymous blocks

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class A from which classes B and C derive. There is an existing anonymous namespace method in class C, say 'callMePlease'. Now, the idea is to pull it out to the parent class. Although it makes more sense to mark this method as Protected @ base class A, I want to know if there is anyway by which we can have this method in anonymous block in A, yet be use-able by B and C.

So,here is my question. If I define a namespace [ anonymous ] in A and define this method 'callMePlease' there, would I be able to use it in say, either B or C?.

This is what I have tried. In my A.hxx, if I declare & define the method, I am able to use it in C.cxx. However, if I declare the method in A.hxx and define its body A.cxx, i am getting a linking error when I try to use it in C.cxx

Can someone please help me understand this?. Is there a way to do this?.

Thanks,
Pavan.

EDIT: current Classes representation

```
class C public A                 

C.cxx                            
namespace
{
void callMePlease()
{
  std::cout<<"Thanks for calling!";
}
}

void methodSpecificToC()
{
  // Do some processing.
  callMePlease();
}

class B public A

B.cxx

void methodSpecificToB()
{
  // Need to call callMePlease here too.
}
```

Comment: A short code can help us to understand it better. Show classes, relations and the problem.

Comment: Classes are in namespaces; namespaces aren't in classes.

Comment: Anonymous namespaces are for static linkage. If `callMePlease` is a method of derived class C why define it in an anonymous namespace?

Comment: @MM. Updated the question to add the detaails.

Comment: @40two I have the same thought too. As mentioned in my question "Although it makes more sense to mark this method as Protected @ base class A", going forward, it makes more sense to have this method as part of the class and not some anonymous namepsace. But want to know how we can solve this problem using anynmous namespaces alone.

Comment: If understood well from the example, `callMePlease` isn't a member function of class C, it's a regular function, you just want it to be statically linked in C.cpp. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in anonymous `namespaces` are visible within the entire translation unit. However, they are not visible externally. In your case `void callMePlease()` will be effectively visible/callable in the `C.cxx` from the point of its definition and below (see code below):

### C.cxx

```
namespace
{
  void callMePlease()
  {
    std::cout<<"Thanks for calling!";
  }
};

void C::methodSpecificToC()
{
  // Do some processing.
  callMePlease(); // callable because is defined above me.
}
```

Comment: So, are you saying that if I declare the method callMePlease in anonymous namespace of base class A.hxx and define its implementation in anonymous namespace of base class implementation A.cxx, the I wont be able to use it in C.cxx?

Comment: No, if you define it in an anonymous namespace in `A.hxx` (which BTW it's a very bad habbit to define functions in header files) and include `A.hxx` in `C.cxx` `callMePlease()` will be callable in `C.cxx`, just because an include directive is being replaced by the pre-compiler with the contents of the file that is being included. However, if you define `callMePlease()` in `A.cxx` it won't be callable from `C.cxx`.

Comment: I got an answer for my question. But want to understand few things here. You said
"Functions in anonymous namespaces are visible within the entire translation unit" - Why would be the method be available in C.cxx if I define the method in A.hxx itself and not A.cxx?. Is it that we would have 2 translation units, 1 for A.hxx and other for A.cxx?.

Comment: When you state in `C.cxx` the directive `#include "A.hxx"`, the pre-compiler will go and replace `#include "A.hxx"` with the contents of file `A.hxx`. As such, if you have defined `callMePlease()` in `A.hxx` it will be visible in `C.cxx` because its definition is copied in `C.cxx` by the pre-compiler. However, this is not the case  if you define `callMePlease()` in `A.cxx`. In that case, it will be visible only in file `A.cxx` from the point of its definition and below.

Comment: @Pavan One translation unit would be "A.hxx" together with "A.cxx" (and all its other includes), and the other would be "A.hxx" together with "C.cxx" (and its other includes). Remember that `#include X` only means "add the contents of file 'X' here". If you define your function in "A.hxx" you will have several definitions, one for each time you include it somewhere. There will be no linking error, because each definition is in a separate anonymous namespace. (Each translation unit has its own anonymous namespace.)